Singularities of complex function $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2}$
I know that the function $ e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has an essential singularity in the origin, but I want to study the function
$$ f(z) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2} $$
Especially using the corollary that states
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n Res(f(z);z_j) + Res(f(z);\infty)=0$$
Where $\sum_{j=1}^n Res(f(z);z_j)$ is the sum of all the residues in the finite.
Kowing that setting $w=1/z$ and $g(w) = f(w)/w^2$ we can demonstrate that
$$ Res(f(z);\infty) = -Res(g(w);w=0) $$
Using this on the function I want to study we have
$$ g(w)=e^w $$
That doesn't have singularity at $w=0$, so we can say that $Res(f(z);\infty) = 0$
Which means that the original function too doesn't have a residue at $z=0$.
I tried to see if even in the Laurent expansion this is true, and we can write, knowing that $ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!\cdot x^n} $$
Which doesn't have the term for $x^{-1}$, therefore there's no residue.
But it doesn't make sense to me, because even from the Laurent expansion we can see that it still has an essential singularity in $z=0$.
I either got some calculations wrong or I didn't get something right.

Origin is an essential singularity with residue $0$. Why is that a  contradiction?

@geetha290krm so a function can have residue 0 at a singularity? Does that mean that no matter on which contour I integrate the function around the origin I have $ \oint_{\gamma} f(z);dz = 0$?

Yes, for sure. $e^{1/z^{2}}$ is another such example.

There is nothing wrong for an isolated singularity (even essential ones) to have residue $0$. Plus, if we replace $z$ by $\frac{1}{z}$ in $\frac{e^{1/z}}{z^2}$, we get $z^2e^z$ which is an entire function, which doesn't look as pathological, but it's really the same function (geometrically), with $0$ and $\infty$ switched.

When $0<|z|<\infty$, $f(z)$ has Laurent expansion:
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2}
=\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{z^n}
=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^3}+\cdots.$$
So $$Res(f(z);\infty)=-a_{-1}=0,\quad Res(f(z);0)=a_{-1}=0,$$
where $a_{-1}$ is the coefficient of $\frac1z$ in the Laurent expansion.
$\infty$ is removeable singularity of $f$ and $0$ is essential singularity of $f$.

By the result that, for $r > 0$
$$
\int_{\partial D_r(0)} z^n = \begin{cases}
2\pi i & n = -1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
one can see that, given a Laurent expansion, integrating is just ''reading off'' the $a_{-1}$ term of the Laurent expansion. This doesn't reflect anything about the nature of the singularity, as there's examples of functions with poles:
$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{1}{z^2} = 0 \quad \text{ with } 0 \text{ order 2 pole}
$$
and with essential singularities:
$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} e^{1/z^2} = 0 \text{ with } 0 \text{ essential singularity}
$$
(as pointed out by @geetha290krm) which have integrals that vanish.
